# Android: Arraylist with multiple elements

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I wonder how to create an arraylist with multiple elements. I have a list like:

```
list1 = ["Circle", Color.WHITE, Color. BLACK, (20,20), (30,30), (40,40)];
```

This array contains String, int(the color) and coordinates. Is that available to put all of them into an arraylist. If so, how can I merge two lists together. Also, how can I get the value from it? I want to generate some list like above and do some code to merge(combine) them. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that this is a follow-up to [How to get same value from different arraylists into one arraylist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263398/how-to-get-same-value-from-different-arraylists-into-one-arraylist).

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to put different types into an arraylist. I think the best solution would be to put all your data (the String "Circle", the colors and the coordinates) into a new class and have an ArrayList with objects of this new class.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it or some links? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this by declaring a `List<Object>`.

```
List<Object> randomBagOfJunk = new ArrayList<Object>();
randomBagOfJunk.add("Circle");
randomBagOfJunk.add(Color.WHITE);
randomBagOfJunk.add(Color.BLACK);
// no idea what a (n, n) is...
```

---

I ***strongly*** recommend that you don't do this, however. Find a different way to store the information. `List<Object>` is almost never the right solution, unless it's storing objects whose class is `Object.class`.

Create a new class to hold your data, and you can write a `merge()` method there as well.

```
class RandomBagOfUsefulThings
{
    String name;
    Color foreground;
    Color background;
    // etc.

    RandomBagOfUsefulThings merge(RandomBagOfUsefulThings other)
    {
        // snip...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what output you want from a list "merge" operation.